# Google Drive SDK: be notified about any file change

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I developed a Python app to access GDrive, now I want to be notified in case **any** file is changed on gdrive.
Specifically I'm interested in move / rename, remove, download and upload events. I see Google provide 2 tools:

1. [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push), but it looks like this is limited to notify changes for a specific file or dir, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18151189/376587).
2. [REST changes API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list), but AFAIU I am supposed to poll the google server every X seconds.

None of this is optimal for me, as I need **global** notifications about all filesystem-related events occurring on gdrive. Are there alternatives? I know DropBox  [supports this](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/announcing-dropbox-webhooks/).

Answer (score 0):

If your app only needs to be notified about changes, a better way as suggested in this [blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-drive-api-push-notifications.html) is to let your app subscribe for changes to a user’s drive and get notified whenever changes occur.

Suppose your app is hosted on a server with `my-host.com` domain and push notifications should be delivered to an HTTPS web-hook `https://my-host.com/notification`:

```
String subscriptionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  Channel request = new Channel()
    .setId(subscriptionId)
    .setType("web_hook")
    .setAddress("https://my-host.com/notification");
  drive.changes().watch(request).execute();
```

With this, as long as the subscription is active, Google Drive will trigger a web-hook callback at `https://my-host.com/notification`. The app can then query the change feed to catch up from the last synchronization point:

```
changes = service.changes().list()
    .setStartChangeId(lastChangeId).execute();
```

As mentioned further, if you are interested in using this new feature, please refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push). You can see push notifications in action with the [Push Notifications Playground](https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/) and view the source at [Github](https://github.com/googledrive/pushnotifications-playground).

Comment: Push notifications have 2 issues: 1 they can't be used to watch all files (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144094/google-drive-sdk-push-notifications-watch-changes-on-all-files/18151189#18151189) 2 they expire after 1 day (this is less severe as I can register again).